# How can I replace a custom tag in string?

Tags: c#

Are there som parsers available that will replace a custom tag for example:
    `[myTag]Some Content[/myTag]` with for example

```
<div class="myTag">Some Content</div>
```

I have tried html agilitypack for this but it doesnt seem to work

I have tried

```
string test = "[myTag]this text is superspecial[/myTag]";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(test);
var output = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("[myTag]");
```

but it doesnt seems like valid xpathexpression

Comment: Showing your efforts so far with HTML Agility Pack, the specific input you were dealing with and the exact code you have written would definitely help us figuring out what might be wrong with your code. With this information missing, your question is pretty much deprived of any context, and meaning. Chances are that if it stays at this state it will get closed pretty fast.

Comment: Do you really have square brackets in your code? `[myTag]` is not a valid HTML tag.

Comment: No this text [myTag]content[myTag] comes from TinyMce and I must parse it. It's like a shortcode in wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.Replace` for every tag you want to change:

```
string s = "[myTag]Some Content[/myTag]";
string newStr = s.Replace("[myTag]", "<div class=\"myTag\">");
string result = newStr.Replace("[/myTag]", "</div>");

Console.WriteLine(result); // output: <div class="myTag">Some Content</div>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx